Rattling "knocking" water pipe on single faucet
Since yesterday 1 of the faucets in our dual sink bathroom vanity creates "knocking" and rattling when turned on. Slowly turning it on will eventually cause it to knock once it hits a certain flow level.
Im not seeing any leaks at the vanity level and the flow leak detector/meter isnt triggering any potential house leak. Although a VERY small infrequent drip could go undetected.
The thing that is interesting is that its only the one faucet, which seems would rule out traditional water hammer. Read online that this could be caused by a blockage? Wonder others thoughts on this. Thank you
Plumbing is circa 2019. No issues till now.
Grohe Concetto faucet


Please add what make and model faucet. It will help with diagnosis.  A guess is there may be a washer that is loose and causes the noise. However there may not be washers in your faucet. We can help better if we know what exactly we are dealing with.

@RMDman Thank you -- updated question / Grohe Concetto

@RMDman -- well, as usual after I got to Home Depot to get the proper socket to take the cartridge out, had lunch - it stopped doing it. The 1 difference is, when it was doing it, the washing machine was on. It was the first time this has ever happened, will monitor. Again, thank you

If you have the instruction booklet, or if you know how, turn off the water, remove and clean the cartridge. That would be the first step. Debris could be causing the vibrations and resulting noise.
Here is a link for the installation sheet. It has pics to guide to removing the cartridge.

awesome -- sunday project here I come

went to clean the cartridge, and it wasnt doing it. Suspect it might be related to the washing machine running at the same time. Will monitor and test
